# Compiler Cost of searching wild char '%%' in like clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a dynamic stored procedure and have to add where clause dynamically in case statement in SQL Server 2008.

My procedure is as below: -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPGETDATA
@STRNAME NVARCHAR(100),
@STRCODE NVARCHAR(100)

AS
BEGIN
SELECT  myTable.*
FROM myTable
WHERE 
IsDELETED = 0  
AND STRNAME LIKE CASE WHEN (RTRIM(LTRIM(@STRNAME))) <> '' THEN 
'%'+ @STRNAME + '%' ELSE '%%' END 
AND STRCODE LIKE CASE WHEN (RTRIM(LTRIM(@STRCODE)) <> '') THEN 
'%' + @STRCODE + '%'  ELSE '%%' END** 

END
```

**The user can select either @strname or @strcode. But not both at a time.**

In that case one like statement is ok but the alternative is always a burden over query because it will always be as

```
@STRNAME like '%%'
```

**or as below**

```
@STRCODE like '%%'
```

Now if I use this approach, will compiler cost some time to search like '%%' even there is nothing to match or will it bypass it and cost nothing? I checked the execution plan also but it displays nothing for the like clause.

Hence I have to use this in webApps so speed of the sp has to consider. And the table has millions of rows.

Execution plan for both are same for both. If I use like cluase in query or remove it from query it shows - Clustred index sacn 100%.

Please help.

Comment: You've made quite a few edits here. Be careful that you don't drastically change the scope of the question while trying to improve it, since you've received several answers. I removed the wiki status from this question.

Comment: Thanks @TimPost , i will take care of the same in future. thanx. Can you plz tell me what is wiki status please?

Comment: 'Community Wiki' means no reputation is gained (or lost) from votes on a post, and the post can be edited by users with only 100 reputation. See [this entry](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki) in the FAQ for more. Wiki status is great for answers that need to evolve over time. It's also automatically applied if any post (question or answer) is edited heavily, to discourage people from 'bumping' their post through edits. You unwittingly tripped that safe guard, which I reverted because it was obviously unintentional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly if either of the columns are nullable then testing `col LIKE '%%'` is not a No-Op but is actually equivalent to testing that the column `col IS NOT NULL` which may well not be the desired effect.

Secondly if the column is not nullable so it truly is a No-Op then this is not a particularly good approach in that SQL Server will **not** optimise out the check. See [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) for better approaches.

Chances are in your case it won't make much difference though.

As you are always doing a search with a leading wildcard against one or other column and you are doing `SELECT *` then likely you will end up with a full table scan anyway.

One case where it could make a difference would be where you have a narrower index on one or more of the columns that could be scanned in preference to scanning the whole clustered index / table. Even there however SQL Server would still need to do book mark lookups to retrieve the `*` so could evaluate the residual predicate quite cheaply for that particular query.

However the plan generated would be completely inappropriate for the invovcation with the other parameter so this attempt at a catch all query could give you a parameter sniffing issue as demonstrated below.

#### Test Table

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
id int primary key,
STRNAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
STRCODE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
IsDELETED BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
Filler CHAR(7000) NULL,
)
INSERT INTO myTable(id, STRNAME, STRCODE)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)), 
       ISNULL(name,type), 
       ISNULL(name,type)
FROM master..spt_values

CREATE INDEX ix ON myTable(STRNAME)
```

#### Invoke first with name parameter (Scan count 1, logical reads 7)

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'
SELECT  myTable.*
FROM myTable
WHERE 
IsDELETED = 0  
AND STRNAME LIKE CASE WHEN (RTRIM(LTRIM(@STRNAME))) <> '''' THEN 
''%''+ @STRNAME + ''%'' ELSE ''%%'' END 
AND STRCODE LIKE CASE WHEN (RTRIM(LTRIM(@STRCODE)) <> '''') THEN 
''%'' + @STRCODE + ''%''  ELSE ''%%'' END 
', 
N'@STRNAME NVARCHAR(100),
@STRCODE NVARCHAR(100)
', @STRNAME = '(rpc)', @STRCODE=''
```

#### Invoke with code parameter reusing same plan (Scan count 1, logical reads 7690)

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'
SELECT  myTable.*
FROM myTable
WHERE 
IsDELETED = 0  
AND STRNAME LIKE CASE WHEN (RTRIM(LTRIM(@STRNAME))) <> '''' THEN 
''%''+ @STRNAME + ''%'' ELSE ''%%'' END 
AND STRCODE LIKE CASE WHEN (RTRIM(LTRIM(@STRCODE)) <> '''') THEN 
''%'' + @STRCODE + ''%''  ELSE ''%%'' END 
', 
N'@STRNAME NVARCHAR(100),
@STRCODE NVARCHAR(100)
', @STRNAME = '', @STRCODE='(rpc)'
```

#### Invoke with code parameter generate specific plan (Scan count 1, logical reads 2517)

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'
SELECT  myTable.*
FROM myTable
WHERE 
IsDELETED = 0  
AND STRNAME LIKE CASE WHEN (RTRIM(LTRIM(@STRNAME))) <> '''' THEN 
''%''+ @STRNAME + ''%'' ELSE ''%%'' END 
AND STRCODE LIKE CASE WHEN (RTRIM(LTRIM(@STRCODE)) <> '''') THEN 
''%'' + @STRCODE + ''%''  ELSE ''%%'' END 
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
', 
N'@STRNAME NVARCHAR(100),
@STRCODE NVARCHAR(100)
', @STRNAME = '', @STRCODE='(rpc)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write something like this:

```
IF COALESCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(@STRNAME))), '') <> '' 
BEGIN
  SELECT  myTable.*
  FROM myTable
  WHERE IsDELETED = 0  
    AND STRNAME LIKE '%'+ @STRNAME + '%'
END
ELSE -- IF COALESCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(@STRCODE))), '') <> '' 
BEGIN
  SELECT  myTable.*
  FROM myTable
  WHERE IsDELETED = 0  
    AND STRCODE LIKE '%'+ @STRCODE + '%'
END
```

Anyway, using LIKE prevents the DB from using indexes. That will be your highest execution cost.

Comment: thanx @user1068993 but i have to use like clause in the where, so is there any issue if i use one like clause where there is some value inside '%some value%' and another where is nothing inside that is as is '%%'

Comment: Execution plan for both are exactle same.

Comment: `LIKE` does not, in itself, prevent use of indexes. It depends what the pattern is. If it doesn't have a leading wildcard then indexes can be used fine. In the parameterised case where it is not known at compile time whether or not it will be run with a leading wildcard or not then SQL Server will (if a suitable covering index exists) use a range seek on the index.

Answer (score 0):

I would create two version of the query, one with `LIKE '%%'` and the other one without it, and then compare their execution plans.

Comment: @GK Ranjan: That might well be the answer. Although I'm not sure if the same would hold true in any situation or only with your data.